# How to build and run a .NET Framework MVC project from command line with MSBuild and IIExpress.exe

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, iis-express

I surprisingly didn't find any good answers after a bit of Googling. With .NET Core I can just do `dotnet run`, but I'm not sure how to do it on my .NET Framework 4.7 project.

I can build with MSBuild like this: `MSBuild.exe *.sln`.

But I can't figure out how to set `IISExpress.exe` to launch my MVC project using the settings Visual Studio uses. Ideas?

Comment: You might refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line to learn IIS Express command line. BTW, VS does not launch your ASP.NET Core app similar to `dotnet run`, so that's a misunderstanding. See https://blog.lextudio.com/how-visual-studio-launches-iis-express-to-debug-asp-net-core-apps-d7fd3677e3c3

Answer (score 4):

For my .NET Framework 4.6.1 project, I was able to start my server by these 2 lines of PowerShell script.

```
PS> cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\"
PS> ./iisexpress /config:E:\Repos\MyProjectFolder\.vs\SolutionName\config\applicationhost.config /site:MyProjectName
```

**To find the equivalent script for your project I recommend the following.**

1. Find the location of `applicationhost.config` file. IIS Express uses this file to start the projects in Visual Studio. It usually resides in `.vs` folder. Here's the complete path `E:\Repos\MyProjectFolder\.vs\SolutionName\config\applicationhost.config`
2. Find `iisexpress.exe`. For me, path is `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe`.
3. Start IIS Express server by specifying the `applicationhost.config` full path and the site you wish to start.

**NOTE:** The site/project must be listed on your `applicationhost.config` file like shown below.

```
     <sites>
         <site name="MyProjectName" id="1">
             <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                 <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="E:\Repos\MyProjectFolder\" />
             </application>
             <bindings>
                 <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44466:localhost" />
                 <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:12435:localhost" />
             </bindings>
         </site>
     </sites>
```